# Showing that $A= \{x=(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in E \mid 0 \leq x_n \leq a_n \}$ is a closed set.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces

> Let $E = \mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$ with the norm $||x||_2 = ( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|x_n|^2 )^{\frac{1}{2}}$. $E$ is a Hilbert space. And let $(a_n) \in E^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that all its terms are either null or positive. Let now $$A=\{x=(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in E \mid 0 \leq x_n \leq a_n  \}$$ 
>   Show that $A$ is closed.

I first was rather confused, as there is little indication to the sequence $(a_n)$, but I think I managed to prove the property of this set.

My first approach was to show that the complementary of $A$ is open, but I struggled to show that any open ball in the complementary is a subset of the complementary. So I decided to show that any sequence with terms in $A$ has its limit in $A$.

First remark: we have the sequence $a=(a_n) \in A$. Suppose that there exists $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$, such that its limit isn't in $A$. Then let $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $||x_k||_{2} \leq ||a||_2$ ( $a=(a_n)$ and remember that $(x_n)$ is a sequence of sequences). Then $0 \leq \lim_{k\to \infty}||x_k||_2 \leq ||a||_2$, and as we supposed that the limit of $(x_n)$ isn't in $A$, then $a$ isn't in $A$, which is absurd. Thus, $A$ is closed.

So is this proof acceptable?

Comment: You can not conclude just from the inequality between norms (where you take the limit) that each coordinate satisfies the same inequality. In other words, the limit could be outside $A$ but have norm less than $\|a\|_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to use the sequential characterisation of closedness, hence you need to assume that $(x_{n})_{n}\subseteq A^{\bf{N}}$. So each $x_{n}\in A^{\bf{N}}$. By writing $x_{n}=(x_{n,1},x_{n,2},...,x_{n,k},...)$ and $0\leq x_{n,k}\leq a_{k}$ and $x_{n}\rightarrow x$, $x=(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{k},...)$, taking limit with $n\rightarrow\infty$ to the inequalities $0\leq x_{n,k}\leq a_{k}$, as $x_{n,k}\rightarrow x_{k}$, we have $0\leq x_{k}\leq a_{k}$, so $x=(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{k},...)\in A$, we are done.

Comment: This is a nice proof, but does your answer imply that my attempted proof is wrong?

Comment: Yes, because you said that $(x_{n})$ isn't in $A$, this is not a correct strategy.

Comment: I spoke about its limit, not $(x_n)$ itself.

Comment: But how would you know whether the limit is not in $A$? Actually we wish to prove that the limit is in $A$.